# Do we need to handle error status code === 0 in front end?

Tags: javascript, angular, error-handling

I'm trying to handle all the error cases using Angular interceptor. One of the tester has come across error status code === 0 and asking me to handle that one too. Do we need to handle error status code 0 in front end? Does that make sense?

Comment: What is status code 0? Do you *currently get this*? If so, what about status code 1-100 - is that also something you encounter?

Comment: Browser returns error code 0 on connection failure. IMO you should handle and give a feedback to user like "you are offline", also you can show some kind of counter to retry the request.

Comment: @VLAZ status code 0 is unknown error.

Comment: @EliasSoares even if we have cors error then also we are getting error code 0

Comment: @EliasSoares "*Browser returns error code 0 on connection failure*" it shouldn't. That's not a standard code. It *might* be used but I sincerely doubt a browser would do this. A library might adopt it but it's still non-standard and *only* to be relied upon when using that library.

Comment: @manojmogalla no, not by the standard it isn't. If you have any tool that *explicitly defines* a zero as "unknown error", *and* you can trust this tool won't decide to follow the HTTP standard all of a sudden, then sure - add a case for it. But asking "What happens if I do an HTTP request and receive a spoon instead of response" is not, *in general*, an answerable question. Because you there shouldn't be any spoons involved in HTTP requests.

Comment: @VLAZ `what about status code 1-100` or maybe `1-99`, as 100 is a standard.  Anyway, the question seems a bit odd, if you can receive an invalid response, then why not handle it?

Comment: @Keith it was supposed to be about the range `[1, 100)` but was too lazy to properly qualify it.

Comment: Let's make it clear: Is this status code the HTTP response's status, or some property, of a JSON object that you receive as a response? For example `{ "status": 0, "description": "Unknown error occured" }` ?

Answer (score 0):

From angular docs: https://indepth.dev/posts/1056/avoiding-common-confusions-with-modules-in-angular

> Something could go wrong on the client-side such as a network error that prevents the request from completing successfully or an exception thrown in an RxJS operator. These errors have **status set to 0** and the error property contains a ProgressEvent object, whose type might provide further information.

So `status = 0` means cilent-side error, maybe the user is disconnected from the network or network is not stable. Whether you want to handle it or not depends on your use case.